# Need Non expiry access Token OR generate the access token for *pre-configured* account

Tags: oauth

My expecting requirement was to generate the access token for
*pre-configured*   account

For example,

We will configure the username and password for google account in our own
configuration settings, while upload the file from
our application, we need to generate the access token for those configured
credential . Kindly validate and assist me.

Answer (score 0):

Access tokens are valid only for 1 Hr, Since you have username and password you can use the same to generate access tokens every 1hr but your question is missing lot of important points,

1. Which OAuth provider are you using google/Azure AD?
2. Which OAuth flow you are going to use? Password credentials flow something similar

You can use any OAuth providers out there. Refer to this link and choose your scenario https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

I believe you can either use authorization code grant flow for your scenario

In Authorization grant flow you get both access token and refresh token and refresh token is long live, you can use refresh token to generate new access tokens every hour.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#libraries

Comment: HI Venkatesh, Thanks for Post. I am using google oauth2.0. Please let me know any other alternate option to achieve this